# How to add data to nested serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add data to my database by rest API and I have some problems with adding the data.
So basically I have added this data from the admin page, but I want to add this from my other python by using requests. When I'm sending post request it shows me that it has been added, but sensor array is empty

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Stacja 1",
        "delay_time": 123,
        "sensor": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "DS18B20",
                "type": "temperature",
                "date_created": "2020-06-26T16:30:28.657804Z",
                "value": 123.0,
                "index": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "DHT22",
                "type": "Humidity",
                "date_created": "2020-06-26T16:30:44.043847Z",
                "value": 1233.0,
                "index": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "DS18B20",
                "type": "temperature",
                "date_created": "2020-06-26T16:37:07.304961Z",
                "value": 1233.0,
                "index": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stacja 1",
        "delay_time": 300,
        "sensor": []
    }
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Sensor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='null', blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='null', blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    value = models.FloatField(null=True)
    index = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ' ' + str(self.type) + ' ' + ' index:' + str(self.index) + ' value:' + str(self.value)


class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='null', blank=True)
    delay_time = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    sensor = models.ManyToManyField(Sensor, null=True, default='null', blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Sensor, Station


class SensorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sensor
        fields = '__all__'


class StationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Station
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

adddata.py

```
import json
import requests
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial(

    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    timeout=1,
    )

payload={
    "username":["xxxxx"],
    "password":["xxxxxxxxx"]
}

while 1:
    x = ser.readline()
    try:
        payload2 = json.loads(x)
        r = requests.post('http://192.168.1.16/api/token/', data=payload)
        jsondata = r.json()
        headers = {}
        headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + jsondata['access']
        print(jsondata['access'])
        r = requests.post('http://192.168.1.16/data/station/', headers=headers, data=payload2)
        print(r.text)
    except:
    continue
```

payload2 looks like

```
{
  "name": "Stacja 1",
  "delay_time": 300,
  "sensor": [
    {
      "name": "DS18B20",
      "type": "temperature",
      "value": 26.5,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "DHT22",
      "type": "temperature",
      "value": 26.5,
      "index": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "DHT22",
      "type": "humidity",
      "value": 66,
      "index": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "battery",
      "type": "voltage",
      "value": 2.104492,
      "index": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: please add text instead of images. It's easier to plug in and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried for single station and multiple sensors, but I guess you will be able to modify it accordingly.

`dataset`

```
{
  "name": "Stacja 1",
  "delay_time": 300,
  "sensors": [
    {
      "name": "DHT22",
      "type": "temperature",
      "value": 26.5,
      "index": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "DHT22",
      "type": "humidity",
      "value": 66,
      "index": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "battery",
      "type": "voltage",
      "value": 2.104492,
      "index": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

`serializers.py`

```
class SensorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sensor
        fields = '__all__'


class StationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sensors = SensorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Station
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        sensor_data = validated_data.pop('sensors')
        station = Station.objects.create(**validated_data)
        station.save()
        for sensor in sensor_data:
            s = Sensor.objects.create(**sensor)
            station.sensors.add(s.id)
        
        return station
```

Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) suggests, object needs to saved before associating it with any model in case of `ManyToManyField`. So your `station` object needs to be saved before you add `ManyToMany` relation to it.

And here is my `views.py`

```
class AddStationAndSensorsView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StationSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = StationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'message': ['Added']}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```

**NOTE:** I have renamed `sensor` to `sensors` in `Station` model.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class Sensor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='null', blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='null', blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    value = models.FloatField(null=True)
    index = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ' ' + str(self.type) + ' ' + ' index:' + str(self.index) + ' value:' + str(self.value)


class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='null', blank=True)
    delay_time = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    sensors = models.ManyToManyField(Sensor, null=True, default='null', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` to your Station serializer:

```
class StationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sensor = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Station
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Comment: I got an error "Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True". I've tried to add queryset but still doesn't work