# Django : list into serializer

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, serialization

I would like to create rest API with Django. I heard about serializers in Django Rest Framework : `from rest_framework import serializers`.
Next, I have to create some sort of models.
I want to create a JSON response of this type :

```
{
  id: "489",
  state: "PREPARATION",
  orderDay: "2020-06-24",
  deliveryDay: "2020-06-30",
  deliveryAddress: "Place des Fêtes",
  comment: "", // facultatif
  products: [
    {
      id: "420",
      name: "Côte de boeuf",
      price: "28.90",
      oldPrice: "", // facultatif
      unit: "KG",
      categoryId: "69666",
      byProducts: [
        {
          id: "420161",
          name: "unité",
          quantity: 42,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

So I have to add a list into my serializers model (*products*, *byProduct*).
Can I do this with serializers and how ?
Thanks by advance

Comment: Do you have any models or serializers that you have tried so far?

Comment: Try following the `DRF` tutorial, it's an excellent package that provides exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603654/how-to-add-data-to-nested-serializers/62619075#62619075)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve such data structure by implementing something like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class ByProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField()


class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    price = serializers.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    oldPrice = serializers.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    unit = serializers.CharField()
    categoryId = serializers.IntegerField()
    byProducts = ByProductSerializer(many=True)


class MainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    state = serializers.CharField()
    orderDay = serializers.DateField()
    deliveryDay = serializers.DateField()
    deliveryAddress = serializers.DateField()
    comment = serializers.DateField()
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True)
```