# Django : handle post JSON requests

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need to handle some JSON data with django.
I will receive this data :

```
{
    "user": 8,
    "orderDay": "2020-06-24",
    "deliveryDay": "2020-06-30",
    "deliveryAddress": "Place des Fêtes",
    "comment": "",
    "orderDetail": 
    [
        {
            "product": 2,
            "byProduct": 2,
            "quantity": 43
        },
        {
            "product": 3,
            "byProduct": 3,
            "quantity": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to save this data in 3 differents table: *order* and *orderDetail*.
**models.py**:

```
class order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(memberArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    orderDay = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deliveryDay = models.DateField()
    deliveryPlace = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    response = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
...
class orderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    byProduct = models.ManyToManyField(byProduct)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
...
class byProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
...
class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prix_uni = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    prix_kg = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    dispo = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    redu = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I don't find any good documentation about how to handle JSON data whith Django.
Thanks by advance

**UPDATE**

I tried something like this:
*serializer.py*:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = product
        fields = '__all__'

class ByProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = byProduct
        fields = '__all__'

class orderDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=order.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = orderDetail
        fields = '__all__'

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    orderDetail = orderDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = order
        fields = ['user', 'comment', 'deliveryDay', 'deliveryAddress', 'orderDetail']

    def create(self, validated_data):
            order_detail_data = validated_data.pop('orderDetail')
            new_order = order.objects.create(**validated_data)
            new_order.save()
            for product in order_detail_data:
                order_detail = orderDetail.objects.create(**product)
                order_detail.order.add(new_order.id)
            
            return new_order
```

*views.py*:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def order(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data['response'] = "Your order went well"
            return Response(data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Comment: same way you have been handling your previous requests. Based on sample data you posted you will need `nested serializers`. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603654/how-to-add-data-to-nested-serializers/62619075#62619075) and this not the exact fit for your data but you will get idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Also if you want an answer make sure to post all related models, it will be easy to try out things. eg `byProduct` is missing.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to check your link ! And I have update my post with the byProduct model

Comment: @neferpitou I tried to do something like in your link, I've updated my post with my updates but unfortunately, it doesn't work for the moment...

Comment: `product` model add that also, after that i will try and also add the related serializers for models.

Comment: Okay, it's done, thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: You have included `Order` model again, plus there is no `serializers` for rest of the models. Please recheck before posting.

Comment: @neferpitou Sorry, I corrected this

Comment: I also modified the JSON data I received, I think it will be easier like that

Comment: @neferpitou And then I edit the serializer.py file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217254/discussion-between-bastien-and-neferpitou).

Comment: @neferpitou Finally it worked, the only problem is the following :  I need the id of the order that I just created, and I don't know how can I find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few changes you need to make.

1. Change your data format:

```
{
    "user": 8,
    "orderDay": "2020-06-24",
    "deliveryDay": "2020-06-30",
    "deliveryAddress": "Place des Fêtes",
    "comment": "",
    "orderDetail": 
    [
        {
            "product": 2,
            "byProduct": [2],
            "quantity": 43
        },
        {
            "product": 3,
            "byProduct": [3],
            "quantity": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

`byProduct` is a `ManyToMany` field so it must have a list of products.

2. In your `orderDetailSerializer`:

```
class orderDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = orderDetail
        fields = ['product', 'byProduct', 'quantity']
```

Take note, in `fields` I have not included `order` because in our data there is no such field, and hence the error, `order field is required`. It's simple because serializer will parse the data we are sending and if there is something missing it will notify us.

3. Changes in `orderSerializer`:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    orderDetail = orderDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = order
        fields = ['user', 'comment', 'deliveryAddress', 'deliveryDay', 'orderDetail']

    def create(self, validated_data):
            order_detail_data = validated_data.pop('orderDetail')
            new_order = order.objects.create(**validated_data)
            # new_order.save()
            for product in order_detail_data:
                by_products = product.pop('byProduct')
                order_detail = orderDetail.objects.create(order=new_order, **product)
                order_detail.byProduct.set(by_products)
                order_detail.save()

            return new_order
```

Few things to notice, `fields` include `orderDetail` although it is not a part of `order` model, but in order to parse the data being passed we need to add such fields, if there are more. Inside `create` method `byProduct` is a `ManyToMany` field, so we will have to use `set()` method in order assign them, `direct assignment` is not allowed.

Comment: I tried to do that but i still got this error : ```{
    "orderDetail": [
        {
            "order": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        },
        {
            "order": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        }
    ]
}```

Comment: Inside `OrderDetailsSerializer` try `order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=order.objects.all())`

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same error... I updated my post with the new OrderDetailSerializer

Comment: I read this documentation : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield and maybe I get this error because the result of `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=order.objects.all())` is a list ? Or maybe there is an error before when I create the new_order ?

Comment: @Bastien I have updated this answer with working version, and removed from there. As it seemed redundant there. Plus anyone with similar type of issue can easily follow.